# Incorrect redirect between action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having some problems when the user wants to move to action games between domains.
Organized at the local version of this:

```
mysite.com/subdomain1/webpage/show?url=about
mysite.com/subdomain2/webpage/show?url=about
```

Globally:

```
subdomain1.mysite.com/webpage/show?url=about
subdomain2.mysite.com/webpage/show?url=about
```

I want to make the user does not enter the main subdomain every time.
For example:
Current page - `subdomain1.mysite.com/webpage/show?url=about`.
I want to see into **`subdomain2`** similar page.
I redirected user to `subdomain2.mysite.com/`.
But i want to redirect user -  `subdomain2.mysite.com/webpage/show?url=about`
without transition at `subdomain2.mysite.com`

How can do it in ASP MVC and C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static string ReplaceSubdomain(this HttpRequest request)
        {
            var urlReferrer = request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri != null ? request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri : string.Empty;
            // Get URl
            var url = request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        #if DEBUG || APPS
            // Search local subdomain
            Regex child = new Regex(@"\b[0-9]?[.]?child[0-9]?");
            // if this request consist of subdomain
            if (child.IsMatch(urlReferrer) && child.IsMatch(url))
            {
                // select subdomain
                var matchUrlRef = child.Match(urlReferrer).ToString();
                var matchUrl = child.Match(url).ToString();
                // if subdomain are not equals
                if ((matchUrlRef != matchUrl))
                {
                    // single out link after local subdomain
                    var urlRefSub = urlReferrer.Remove(0, urlReferrer.IndexOf(matchUrlRef) + matchUrlRef.Length);
                    var urlSub = urlReferrer.Remove(0, url.IndexOf(matchUrl) + matchUrl.Length);
                    // validate link query after subdomain
                    // if different url query - replace subdomain
                    if (urlReferrer.Length > urlSub.Length)
                        return urlReferrer.Replace(urlRefSub, urlSub);
                }
            }
            return url;
        #else
 

            //  Check if before page are existsand subdomain are equls
            if (!SubDomainRoute.GetSubdomain(urlReferrer).Equals(SubDomainRoute.GetSubdomain(url)))   
                // if subdomain really exist for "child"
                if (SubDomainRoute.GetSubdomain(urlReferrer).Contains("child") 
                        && SubDomainRoute.GetSubdomain(url).Contains("child"))
                    return url.Replace(SubDomainRoute.GetSubdomain(url),
                                                           SubDomainRoute.GetSubdomain(urlReferrer));
            return request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        #endif
        }
```

Sorry if i distract you and spend your time - I myself found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

How do you make links (anchors) in views? If you use ActionLink method, you can write a wrapper method, e.g. SubdomainActionLink, which would do the same, but also insert "subdomain2" to the href path. If you need do such a redirection inside codebehind, simply get current request url and replace subdomain number.